# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype' appeared suddenly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dtype

I have df with features in my google colab, and suddenly appeared error:

Code:

```
df_features['cooling'] = df['cooling'].astype('object')
df_features['view'] = df['view'].astype('object')
cat_features = ['cooling', 'view', 'city_region']
X = df_features.drop('target', axis=1)
y = df_features['target']

num_cols = [col for col in X.columns if X[col].dtype in ['float64','int64']]
cat_cols = [col for col in X.columns if X[col].dtype not in ['float64','int64']]
```

Here is error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
5 y = df_features['target']
6
----> 7 num_cols = [col for col in X.columns if X[col].dtype in ['float64','int64']]
8 cat_cols = [col for col in X.columns if X[col].dtype not in ['float64','int64']]
9

```
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I already tried to use !pip install --upgrade pandas  but it had no success

Answer (score 3):

You seem to somehow get back a DataFrame and not a Series by calling `X[col]`. Not sure why, because you did not supply the full structure and data of your dataframe.

`.dtype` is for pandas Series https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dtype.html

`.dtypes` is for pandas Dataframes (and seems also to work with pandas Series) https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html

Answer (score 2):

`df[col]` will return a `DataFrame` object (not a `Series`) if `df` contains more than one column with the same name. Make sure you do not have more than one column with the same name in `df` as that is the likely source of this error.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly my problem. Saved me lots of debugging :-)